# When I pay off my mortgage loan, what would really happen?

Tags: mortgage, bonds

Correct me if I'm wrong. I understand that when I open a mortgage loan, some underlying bond is issued and purchased by some investors. When the rate is much lower and I refinance and close my previous loan, what happens behind the scenes? Is the underlying security closed at the same time? Or was it changed hands?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The underlying investment is usually somewhat independent of your mortgage, since it encompasses a bundle of mortgages, and not only yours. It works similarly to a fund. When, you pay off the old mortgage while re-financing, the fund receives the outstanding debt in from of cash, which can be used to buy new mortgages.